# Why do I end up with an empty file when using "cp" or "mv"?

Tags: sh, cp, mv

I am trying to overwrite an existing file with another. 
I am replacing a file that exists by doing the following:

```
cp -f /tmp/workspace.xml > /system/TEST/workspace.xml
```

The new file created is unfortunately empty and does not contain anything from the original file.

I've also tried the following but I get the same result.

```
mv -f /tmp/workspace.xml > /system/TEST/workspace.xml
```

Why is that?

Comment: Apologies. Long day. Can you maybe explain why the new file created is empty and does not copy the context of the original file?

Comment: "How do I use `cp`" is not really a programming question. Try https://superuser.com/?

Comment: `cp` doesn't write to standard output; it creates a new file itself.

Answer (score 2):

don't use the redirection operator ( `>` ) for `mv` or `cp` also you don't need to address the name of the file in the location you want to overwrite

```
  mv -f folder_with_file_to_move/workspace.xml destination_folder_with_file_to_overwrite
```

Comment: Thank you I will give it a try now.

Answer (score 2):

The `>` redirects the *output* of the command. It doesn't tell the command where to put the file. The output of the copy command with insufficient arguments is nothing, so you get an empty file.

Remember that `>` redirects "STDOUT" only, and there's another output channel called STDERR which must be redirected separately.

The correct way to copy a file:

```
cp -f /tmp/workspace.xml /system/TEST/workspace.xml
```

You can also move it:

```
mv -f /tmp/workspace.xml /system/TEST/workspace.xml
```

You'll only employ `>` if you care about capturing output, like in this case:

```
cat /tmp/workspace.xml > /system/TEST/workspace.xml
```

Which in this case channels the output of `cat` to the target file, which works because that's what `cat` is supposed to do.

Comment: OK "mv" has worked and the file is there with full contents but now I have the issue of it not setting the correct permissions. Is it possible to add that to the command?

Comment: That's a good question, but outside of the scope of this one. It's worth qualifying what you mean by that in a new question so it can be addressed properly.

Comment: If you don't rename the file, you can just use the target directory as the last argument.

Comment: Thanks all working now. I just added the chmod command at the end to set permissions.